# FlipBoard App Like Page Flip animation in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to add flipBoard like animation to my news app. Please help how to implement it.
Like This : [Flip View](http://openaphid.github.com/blog/2012/05/21/how-to-implement-flipboard-animation-on-android/)

Answer (score 0):

You can find good examples here

http://rhizohm.net/irhetoric/post/2010/11/09/Page-Transition-Animations-and-Windows-Phone-7.aspx

http://wpfbookcontrol.codeplex.com/

www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/controls/book.aspx

Comment: :I am looking for vertical half page flip

Comment: Vertical half page flip? Can you explain more in your question